# Issue installing "JetDrive 720" SSD to MBP late 2012 Retina

Tags: backup, high-sierra, ssd

I have a Retina macbook Pro late 2012 running OS X High Sierra version 10.13.4. I have decided to upgrade my SSD because 120GB is not enough, therefore, I bought a JetDrive 720 SSD (240GB) from Amazon to perform a DIY upgrade.

It should be pretty straight forward but I am having the following error when I try to clone the original drive into the new drive.

[image]

I have followed the instructions from the manufacturer but it simply isn't working. Instructions: [Transcend JetDrive 720 Manual](https://www.transcend-info.com/Software/1156/)

I suspect that the issue is with APFS.

Comment: Using Disk Utility, can you partition and erase the drive?

Comment: I’m currently attempting one option: I’ve downloaded Carbon Copy Cloned software and so far it appears to be cloning the Macintosh HD to the JetDrive. If it doesn’t work i’ll Try to partition.

Comment: It appeared to work flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to download Carbon Copy Cloner software because apparently Disk Utility and APFS created a bug after High Sierra update. Just connect your JetDrive or any other drive, follow the prompts and press "clone". That should work for everybody.